# Counting elements of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}(\alpha)$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I have the field $K=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, I proved that the polynomial $P(X)=X^3+X^2+1$ is irreducible.
Then I know that the quotient $K[X]/P$ is a field of $8$ elements. 
Let now $\alpha$ be a root in an extension of $K$, as $\alpha$ is algrebaic, we have $K[\alpha]$ isomorphic to $K(\alpha)$.

> It's asking to enumerate elements of $K(\alpha)$

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Enumerate all polynomials of degree less than $3$  with coefficients in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Comment: So it's $K[X]/P$ which is rest modulo $P$ right ? i get $X^2+1,X^2,X+1,X,1$ . So $\alpha^{-1}$ is $-X^2-X$ ?

Comment: No quite. $\alpha^{-1}=\alpha^2+\alpha$ since $-1=1$. You have $8$ polynomials with degree less than $3$.

Comment: I forgot $X^2+X+1,X^2+X$ and $0$. Thanks a lot.